# Comma is causing unwanted string split

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, split

I have an array of data sent from my database - Once received, I save it in shared preferences - here is my getter:

```
public List getAnswerStringEdit() {
        return answer_edit;
    }
```

I save it as so:

```
editor.putString(Constants.ANSWER_EDIT,resp.getAnswer().getAnswerStringEdit().toString().trim());
```

Then retrieve it here:

```
String answerString = pref.getString(Constants.ANSWER_EDIT, "").trim();
        answerString = answerString.substring(1, answerString.length() - 1).trim();
        String[] array = answerString.split(",");
```

Finally, I access the array as so:

```
et_answer1_edit.append(array[0]);
```

My problem is this - Say I add a questions which has a comma in the middle of it, like -

Question 1- "**Why is this broke, I don't know?**"

Currently, when I retrieve my question, the string is getting split, even though there are quotation marks around the whole question/answer- So in the example above, in position 0 in the array, I should have:

"**Why is this broke, I don't know**?"

However, instead I am getting in position 0:

**Why is this broke** - then position 1 as: **I don't know**

I know this sounds daft because clearly, I am calling for the split to happen on the comma, but I expect that at the end of the whole string object, not in the middle of it.

The retrieved JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "message": "Answer Has Been Selected",
    "answer": {
        "answer_edit": ["Why is this broke, I don't know?", "What is your favorite song, because I want to know"]
    }
}
```

Any help/advice that can help me to understand what is causing this, would be really appreciated.

Comment: Rather than splitting based on comma you have to try splitting for the question marks.

Comment: It's json, treat as json.

Comment: @TominB What if there's a quote in the question?

Comment: @Displayname Without context that means nothing. If you want to pretend it's not json then use a CSV parsing library or try to write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all the suggest answers, figured out a simple solution:

First I stored my answers sent from my external database as so -

```
final String jsonAnswers = gson.toJson (resp.getAnswer().getAnswerStringEdit());
```

Then saved in shared pref -

```
editor.putString(Constants.ANSWER_EDIT,jsonAnswers);
```

Next to read the answer back out:

```
String answerString = pref.getString(Constants.ANSWER_EDIT, "").trim();
final String[] array = gson.fromJson (answerString, String[].class);
```

Finally, I could set my Edittext with data from the array:

```
et_answer1_edit.append(array[0].trim());

et_answer2_edit.append(array[1].trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont split the string using ',' use this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(answerString );
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("answer").getJSONArray("answer_edit");
            Log.e("Json Array elements are","First Element : "+jsonArray.get(0)+"\nSecond Element : "+jsonArray.get(1));
            String QuestionString1 = jsonArray.get(0).toString();
            String QuestionString2 = jsonArray.get(1).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("your json response");

try 
  {
      JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("answer");

      JSONArray jsonArray = data.getJSONArray("answer_edit");
      Log.e("=>", "" + jsonArray);

      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
      {
         String value = jsonArray.getString(i);

         String[] parts = value.split(Pattern.quote(","));

          for (int j=0; j<parts.length; j++)
          {
            Log.e("Answer String ", "=" + parts[j]);
          }
     }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
E/=>: ["Why is this broke, I don't know?","What is your favorite song, because I want to know"]
E/Answer String: =Why is this broke
E/Answer String: = I don't know?
E/Answer String: =What is your favorite song
E/Answer String: = because I want to know
```

Comment: if there is not comma in a one question then  **part2 = parts[1];** it's causing Exception.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("your json response");

try 
  {
      JSONObject answer= jsonObject.getJSONObject("answer");

      JSONArray jsonArrayAnswerEdit = answer.getJSONArray("answer_edit");
      Log.e("=>", "" + jsonArrayAnswerEdit);
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayAnswerEdit.length(); i++){
          String que= jsonArrayAnswerEdit.getString(i);
          Log.e("json", i + "=" + que);
     }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```